# Deleting rows in Excel using powershell

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, csv

I have a csv file which has a series of pin-codes in column A but the first row/cell (A1) is empty and I need to delete the whole row using Powershell,
any ideas?

I have tried this but it did nothing!

```
(gc C:\TEMP\test\NewGroup17.csv) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content C:\TEMP\test\NewGroup18.csv
```

Comment: Trim will not work as it will trim characters from beginning and end of a row, not a whole row at once. You will need to load in the CSV as array and then remove the first item of the array, then save the array back to CSV.

Comment: Don't do it in PowerShell but rather use Excel, select the column and just delete it. If you want to delete the whole column using PowerShell you will need to read each line and modify it and/or use `Import-CSV` and modify each object.

Answer (score 1):

This will skip the first row:

```
       $myFile = @(import-csv NewGroup17.csv -Encoding default)
       $i = 0
       foreach ($row in $myFile){
          if($i -gt 0){
          $myNewFile += $row
          }
          $i++
       }
       $myNewFile | export-csv (NewGroup18.csv) -NoTypeInformation -Encoding default
```